# How to Run only one function in onCreate on every rotation of a device in android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, bundle, bundler, screen-rotation

For every rotation of a device **onCreate** function is called and all data lost. But I need to run a particular function in **onCreate** for every rotation of device.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.!! Please share some code samples you tried and also show the behavior you expect if possible. For more information on how to ask a good question on SO, please go through this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask :)

Comment: You can use viewmodel to avoid data loss after device rotation.